# Why am I still question banned?

Tags: support, post-ban, banning

Can you explain why I'm still banned? Is this definitive or could the ban be lifted in future?

I've read the Help Center articles and [this FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). It says I need to improve my questions, but unfortunately all my questions were very simple typographical errors.

I understand that Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. How can I get out of the ban?

Comment: Those types of questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Hopefully now that you know that, you can delete your questions and/or a moderator can un-ban you.

Comment: @Brad: Moderators do not have the power to lift a question ban.

Comment: @Brad Deleting the questions won't remove the question ban (it'll just make things worse).  A moderator cannot explicitly unban a post banned user.

Comment: i have read that, but have you my question seen ?
It's typographically or error on line x ....

Comment: SO specifically does not want typo questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because they're unlikely to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: I've now heard afterwards but now I have serious trouble. 
Is there a way to delete this account so I can start from scratch with a new?

Comment: @averroken How would that be helpful?  You've been banned because you've demonstrated an inability to post quality content over an extended period of time.  You were given opportunities to improve, despite feedback that your questions were problematic, and you chose not to improve.  The whole point of post banning you is because you have demonstrated that you're not capable of posting questions that we would want here.  Why would we want you to just delete your account and start over?  The whole point of the ban is to stop you from asking questions that we'll just need to remove.

Comment: @averroken that can be seen as fraudulent behavior. I don't recommend creating a new account, just so that you can evade your current question ban.

Comment: But there is no other way to do?

Comment: There are no short cuts @averroken. You'll have to put in some elbow grease and either tune up your questions or contribute in other ways.

Comment: @averroken the best way to lift a question ban is to improve your current questions. Once they've been improved, you can ask people to review them and perhaps reopen or upvote them. Either that, or make other positive contributions to the site, like answering questions or editing other people's posts to improve them.

Comment: I think averroken is asking how to redeem his account. He seems to understand why he is banned, and what he should not do. But left with no chance of improving the content, cause it is horrible. Deleting it now counts towards more banning. Give him advice on how he is now able to contribute or content which he can improve upon. Else there will just be a new account that is unrelated to the current one with the old story repeated.

Comment: I want to just say this: the OP has been trying to improve his questions. He visited the [php room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) several times to get tips and answers. He has been doing this for the last few weeks. I pity the OP because he's really trying. I've come to the conclusion that the questions he has posted are irrecoverable. Now the question is "what is the solution?" or "is there even a solution?". The questions can't be improved, if the OP will delete them it's also bad. I hope he can lift the ban by answering questions.

Comment: And don't just focus on negatively scored questions. Even making good questions great, or reasonable questions better will help

Comment: @RobertHarvey That makes sense, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @averroken I looked at all of your questions and tried to improve them as best as I could, but they were generally the type of questions that we highly discourage on [main]. Do you have any deleted questions that you could list in this question? Maybe people can help you improve those too.

Comment: @Cupcake: The juxtaposition makes me lol.

Comment: I have no. deletend questions, iT was deleted Answers

Comment: I have this undeleted

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to quote some parts of [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) which are pertinent to this questions comments:

> ### How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
>
> [...] Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts! ... Note the emphasis on fixing. Do not delete your posts.
>
> If you are banned from asking questions, then **writing a few quality
> answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again**. But
> as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for
> sure. [...]
>
> ### Can I simply create a new account?
>
> **No**. The automatic ban is at a lower level than account.

Comment: Then vote this up please(this are good answers):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963175/how-to-fix-tabs-in-excel-export-php/22661404#22661404
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273731/wrong-syntax-mysql-php/20273761#20273761

Comment: I think begging people on Meta to upvote your questions could very well have the opposite effect.

Comment: Go make new good answers on good questions. They'll get seen a lot more than old answers.

Comment: @averroken [this answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20273761/456814) isn't that great. It's one line of code with no explanation. I'm not upvoting that. Also, try really hard not to answer bad questions too. That's a **really bad** question. **It has a high chance of being deleted.**

Comment: the first link is with more explanation but it's an older question

Comment: @averroken updated previous comment, it's kind of important, please read that, don't answer bad questions, it's a waste of your time.

Comment: You can create another account with another email address :)

Comment: @AdrianB - If they do to get around the QB and are caught, there will be worse penalties.