# Is there a way I can retrieve my deleted questions in an attempt to remove my question ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

I've been contributing for a long time, but most of it was not what you would consider good contributions.

When I started out here at Stack Overflow, I was a newbie. Like most, I have been guilty of asking bad questions on multiple occasions. Of course, these questions would get the down vote, so I would delete them out of vanity.
 I don't expect to get sympathy. I knew the rules when I signed up and I didn't heed the warnings.

However, I would like the chance to vindicate myself if possible, by un-deleting my long deleted questions and getting them moved to the community wiki.

Many of my early questions were obvious syntax mistakes and other common noob areas. I was thinking it would be possible to turn it into a guide to common syntax mistakes in PHP, geared towards newbies in common, easy to understand language for people who are not yet familiar with the lingo. Any suggestions, tips or help is greatly appreciated it. I always appreciated it.

Side note: I will additionally make a conscious effort to improve my grammar and punctuation.

Comment: Your profile only shows 2 questions for me so I assume you deleted some.  You need to improve and undelete those questions if you want the question ban to be lifted.

Comment: In roughly six months you've had 11 net positive answers to the community out of 35.  Looking at your two questions, I see them being somewhat confusing or unclear as to the full intent, but there are answers to them (and they don't seem downvoted).  I can't see your deleted questions, of course - and that may be playing the largest role out of them all.

Comment: @Anonymous The questions were basically noob questions. things like a missing brace here, an undefined variable. useless waste of space.

Comment: Any deleted question plays a role in the question ban.  That may be what was causing it - you asked a few too many of those "noob" questions and the algorithm didn't like it.

Comment: @r3wt Those could be very good questions.  They just need to be properly researched and attempted to be debugged with a clear problem statement.

Comment: @Makoto, so if i were to undelete the questions, and transform them into legitimate questions it might maybe be lifted? i really need to ask a question about maintaining aspect ration of an image upload. -_-

Comment: Not necessarily.  I don't know how you would transform a "noob" question such as missing a brace here or an undefined variable there into viable, on-topic questions.

Comment: @Makoto Maybe i could transform it into a Checklist for common noob mistakes and syntax errors.

Comment: @r3wt That would not be considered an on-topic question, and would probably recieve further downvotes. =/

Comment: @JeremyBanks well what else can i do? create another account? continue down the path of solving all of my own problems, never truly knowing one way or another if i used the best possible solution to the problem?

Comment: Don't be tempted to create sock puppet accounts to get round the question ban - this will be detected and will get you banned for longer.

Comment: @slugster not implying that i would.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254060/why-am-i-still-question-banned/ It's likely that *good answers* will eventually lead to to un-question-bans.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13203/188965) seems to be the direct answer to your question.

Comment: Am not sure that you can

Answer (score 5):

> I would like the chance to vindicate myself if possible, by un-deleting my long deleted questions and getting them moved to the community wiki.

That's not what community wiki is for. A moderator won't (or at the very least shouldn't) convert posts to CW for you in a case like this.

There are two ways you could retrieve your deleted posts:

1. If they were posted and deleted recently, you can access them from your profile. Under the "questions" tab there is a "deleted recent questions" link. It will show you questions you made in the past 60 days that were subsequently removed.
2. Failing #1, email us via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page on the site. Explain what you're trying to do and one of the [community managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) will figure out the best way to help you, if possible.

Having said all that, you're not currently blocked from asking questions, so I would just carry on and take extra care with future posts.

Comment: "you're not currently blocked from asking questions" I know, but i resolved my problem on my own already. If i need to ask a question in the future, ill make it count. thx