# Why am I still banned from asking questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Per the advice in this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254060/why-am-i-still-question-banned), I have done:

1. Improve the existing questions
2. Don't delete questions with negative scores

I have lots of plus points:

1. I have no recently deleted questions
2. I earn some reputation daily, see below:

   [image: recent reputation gains]

What else can I do to get unbanned? Should the moderators be able to remove the ban if the user's behaviour has improved?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am discuss about the point for `unbanned` question I Know this Duplicate. I have also include `link` in the question see the question.

Comment: Looking through your reputation history, most of it is points gained from answers. Question ban is based on the quality of your questions. I think it's better that moderators can't unban people, or we'd get even more sob stories on meta of how people try so hard, get so far, but in the end it doesn't really matter.

Comment: That's it. That's all the advice. Still banned? Keep trying to improve.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I Have Improve the Question see and Remove the Duplicate.

Comment: @TZHX I Improve the question see the edit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you have say `Keep trying to Improve` I Asked only 4 question then how can I Improve in those `4 question`  `1. Duplicate `, `1 have positive vote`  and `2 are typo question`.

Comment: You've deleted at least one post with a score -3 or lower. Was that not a question? Your questions on meta recently hardly suggest you've truly improved your ability to ask questions. That you think the edit was an improvement further suggests you don't know what is meant by improvement.

Comment: This is unfortunate, since you have been so very successful in getting your answers accepted and upvoted recently:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst you have no recently deleted questions, you have 7 questions which have been historically (albeit not recently) deleted.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458359/how-to-i-extract-the-data-from-the-datamatrix-barcode
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453885/how-to-get-child-page-metadata-files
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435993/from-where-download-android-apidemos-for-version-1-3-2
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391667/why-resource-from-resource-file-is-not-loaded-properly
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311119/how-load-mysql-table-to-datagridview-of-c-sharp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152491/angular-xeditable-editable-selected-row
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134254/how-to-edit-row-when-row-is-selected-without-check-box-in-angular-js-xeditable

Of these 7,

- 4 have a negative score
- 3 have a score of 0
- None of them have a positive score

... and the average score for all your questions (deleted and undeleted) is -0.63, which is *likely*  (moderators cannot tell exactly) why you're still question banned.

Your best chance of getting yourself out of your ban is by editing your downvoted & deleted questions into shape, then undeleting them, in the hope they accrue upvotes. Moderators cannot lift your question ban.

Comment: that's point are very useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Harshad note that you will likely need to [flag moderator to undelete before you can edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322437/does-undeleting-questions-help-to-unban-an-account/322438?noredirect=1#comment341178_322438) (can't tell if this is so for self-deleted questions) - that is, to avoid it getting more downvotes, you'd better prepare improved revision off-line and write it over old one as soon as question is undeleted, the faster the better

Comment: I have an average question score of -1.4.  Maybe I should ask something just to see if I'm banned.

Comment: So low-quality questions are discouraged but a user gets banned if he realizes he had bad questions and cleans them up?

Comment: @Andrea Not really, no. From all reports, deletion of questions has very little impact on the question ban. It's more likely the having bad questions that is getting the user banned.

Comment: @TZHX, ok that makes more sense. Thank you for the clarification.